# How to sort two fields in Solr 3.6

Tags: solr

In the web request url there is a "sort" option. However, how do i sort by two fields? If I do something like:

```
 sort=field1 asc&sort=field2 desc
```

Only the first field will be used for sorting upon my observations.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you do it this way:

```
sort=field1 asc, field2 desc
```

Comment: That is correct, however if field1 is "score", the second sort is virtually worthless since "score" is rarely (at least in my experience w/ my data) the same on two documents.  Please correct me if I am wrong, but that that's been my experience.

Comment: Mike, thanks for pointing this out! :) In my case, the field1 is a score, but it is normalized; and field2 is distance. So, i think this works fine for my case.

Answer (score 2):

SOLR(3.6.2)
but if you want to sort additional **intField** in couple with *'score'*
try to search instead of:

```
sort=score desc,intField desc
```

this one:

```
sort=intField desc,score desc
```