# Is it possible to sort by 2+ fields using json.facet?

Tags: sorting, solr, facet

I'm using the following json.facet query:

```
{buckets:
   {terms:
     {field:outlet,
      limit:10,
      sort:{numberofhits:desc},
      facet:
       {numberofhits:'sum(numberofhits)',
        mediavalue:'sum(mediavalue)',
        audience:'sum(audience)',
        positivesentiment:'sum(positivesentiment)',
        negativesentiment:'sum(negativesentiment)',
        dmaid:'max(dmaid)',
        actorfriendscount:'sum(actorfriendscount)'}}}}
```

Everything works great, except that I want to be able to sort by numberofhits and then by the document count. I thought that, since document count is the default sort, this would happen automatically. But what it's actually doing is sorting by numberofhits and then by outlet alphabetically.

I tried sort:{numberofhits:desc,count:desc}, but it ignores the second one. Is there any way to specify two sort fields?

Comment: Is the numberOfHits field a score. Because, the sort depends on this. Please look into this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804322/how-to-sort-two-fields-in-solr-3-6). For complete theory on the sort operation look [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#q)

Comment: It's not a score. It's a count of the number of times a search term is found within the text of a document. The links you provided are referring to the base sort parameter. Is that the same thing as the json.facet sort? I was under the impression the base sort couldn't operate on facet results.